# strange behavior for activity, when generating APK vs testing app

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

so i have this code in my app, it collects information while the application is not in focus using a "locationListenerFunc = new LocationListener" service, 
and then when the application resumes focus, it uses this information to display a line on map, 
WHEN I TEST the application and mimimize it, then opens the application back up, everything works great, the application is in the same state as i left it, and does everything it suppose to do.
WHEN I GENERATE APK and test it that way, it works, but when i close it, then open it back up, it sort of restarts itseld, the activity is NOT in the same state as i left it.(further testings show that when i resume the app it goes into the onCreate again, instead of on resume)

does anyone know why does this happening ?

here is my code for the main activity >

```
package -----;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.text.format.Time;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.CameraPosition;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.
    private Button startTrackingButton;
    private Button stopTrackingButton;
    private TextView mainText;
    private Boolean isInPause = false;
    private List<LocationItems> locationItemsList = new ArrayList<LocationItems>();
    private double ladHistory = 0;
    private double logHistory = 0;
    private LocationManager manager;
    private LocationListener locationListenerFunc;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.map_fragment_layout);

        //casting
        startTrackingButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BTStartTracking);
        stopTrackingButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BTStopTracking);
        mainText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TVMainTextView);

        stopTrackingButton.setEnabled(false);

        //GPS LOCATION MANAGER
        manager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListenerFunc = new LocationListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                ///
                Log.d("myTag", "onlocation change ?");
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                        new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                        .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                        .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                        .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                        .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                //sets text & lat, long>
                Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
                today.setToNow();

                double Lad = location.getLatitude();
                double Long = location.getLongitude();
                mainText.setText("lat: " + String.valueOf(Lad) + ", " + "long: " + String.valueOf(Long) + ", last update at: " + today.format("%k:%M:%S"));


                //add a line on map
                if ((ladHistory != 0) && (logHistory != 0)) {

                    PolylineOptions line =
                            new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(ladHistory,
                                            logHistory),
                                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(),
                                            location.getLongitude()))
                                    .width(30).color(Color.RED);

                    mMap.addPolyline(line);

                }


                //updates veraibles
                ladHistory = location.getLatitude();
                logHistory = location.getLongitude();

                //handles all polylines lost while application was offline:
                if (isInPause == true) {
                    locationItemsList.add(new LocationItems(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
                }

                ///
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

            }
        };


        //stops tracking button touch listener
        stopTrackingButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                //handles the disabling and starting of buttons
                stopTrackingButton.setEnabled(false);
                startTrackingButton.setEnabled(true);

                //removing locaion updates
                manager.removeUpdates(locationListenerFunc);
                manager = null;

                mainText.setText("stopped location update");

            }
        });

        //starts tracking button touch listener
        startTrackingButton.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do stuff here
                Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
                today.setToNow();

                mainText.setText("location update started at:  " + today.format("%k:%M:%S"));

                manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

                manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        1000, 0, locationListenerFunc);


                //handles the disabling and starting of buttons
                startTrackingButton.setEnabled(false);
                stopTrackingButton.setEnabled(true);


            }
        });


        //setting up map
        setUpMapIfNeeded();


    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        isInPause = false;

        //repaints all lost points
        for (int i = 0; i < locationItemsList.size() - 1; i++) {

            LocationItems sourceItem = (LocationItems) locationItemsList.get(i);
            LocationItems destinationItem = (LocationItems) locationItemsList.get(i + 1);

            PolylineOptions line =
                    new PolylineOptions().add(new LatLng(sourceItem.getLatiduteVar(),
                                    sourceItem.getLongitudeVar()),
                            new LatLng(destinationItem.getLatiduteVar(),
                                    destinationItem.getLongitudeVar()))
                            .width(30).color(Color.RED);

            mMap.addPolyline(line);

            //zeroes the lists
            locationItemsList = new ArrayList<LocationItems>();

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        isInPause = true;

    }

    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

        manager.removeUpdates(locationListenerFunc);
        manager = null;

    }


    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                centerMapOnMyLocation(); //centers the map on user location
            }
        }
    }

    private void centerMapOnMyLocation() {

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false));

        if (location != null) {

            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                    new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), 13));

            CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                    .target(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))      // Sets the center of the map to location user
                    .zoom(17)                   // Sets the zoom
                    .bearing(90)                // Sets the orientation of the camera to east
                    .tilt(30)                   // Sets the tilt of the camera to 30 degrees
                    .build();                   // Creates a CameraPosition from the builder
            mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


            //sets text >
            double Lad = location.getLatitude();
            double Long = location.getLongitude();
            mainText.setText("lat: " + String.valueOf(Lad) + ", " + "long: " + String.valueOf(Long));


        }

    }

}
```

and here is my menifest file >

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="-----" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="-------" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MapsActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible your app gets shut down, if your device for some reason has low memory. You could try to make a Toast in inDestroy, to see when it gets killed. To work around that, you could make an actual `Service` that you start and stop with your buttons, those don't get stopped so easily.

Update:

As far as I can see you're only putting a listener in place, which gets destroyed with its activity.

Instead, make a new class `GPSListeningService extends Service`(for example), start it on button press `startService(new Intent(this, GPSListenerService.class))`, and use that for tracking. You can communicate between those with static vars (maybe let the service class hold a static reference to the object and use that from teh MapActivity), or broadcasts, or IBinder (no idea how this one works, it's just here for completeness)...I'm sure you'll think of something. Maybe also use an `IntentService`, those open another thread to do their work, not sure if that's neccessary.

Comment: i'm sure it destroys the aplication, i am opening an actual service .. no ?